# Derefernecing a pointer changes its value

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to implement rust-style vectors in c, which is defined as

```
typedef struct
{
    int *ptr,              // pointer to starting element
    int len,               // length of the vector
    int cap,               // capacity; it does not reallocate the whole vector till len == cap
} vector;
```

I got almost everything working, except the get-value function. Calling vec_getval function **always** changes the 3rd and 4th elements to 1936877926 and 10 respectively, no matter the length of the vector. Here is all the relevant code with error checking omitted:

```
#define ELEMENT_SIZE sizeof(int)

extern vec_data vec_getval(vector *vec, size_t index)
{
    return *(vec->ptr + (ELEMENT_SIZE * index));
}

extern void vec_push(vector *vec, vec_data val)
{
    if (vec->len < vec->cap)                                    // Don't reallocate if length < capacity
    {
        *(vec->ptr + (ELEMENT_SIZE * vec->len)) = val;
        vec->len++;
        return;
    }

    realloc(vec->ptr, ELEMENT_SIZE * (vec->len + 1));
    *(vec->ptr + (ELEMENT_SIZE * vec->len)) = val;
    vec->len++;
    vec->cap++;
}

extern void vec_with_capacity(vector *vec, size_t cap)
{
    vec->ptr = (int *)malloc(ELEMENT_SIZE * cap);
    vec->cap = cap;
    vec->len = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    vector vec;

    vec_with_capacity(&vec, 5);
    vec_push(&vec, 50u);
    vec_push(&vec, 15u);
    vec_push(&vec, 40u);
    vec_push(&vec, 80u);
    vec_push(&vec, 70u);

    printf("first value\t: %d\n", vec_getval(&vec, 0)); // Works as expected, but changes 3rd and 4th elements
    printf("third value\t: %d\n", vec_getval(&vec, 2)); // Does not work fine!
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
first value     : 50
third value     : 1936877926
```

Comment: I see `third` in your print statement. Where is it in the printout???

Comment: BTW, change `(ELEMENT_SIZE * index)` to `index` and it should work. Because your pointer is of type `int*`, this pointer arithmetic is done by the compiler. The only reason to do it youreslf would be if that pointer was of type `char*`.

Comment: @archbishop For example this expression *(vec->ptr + ( * vec->len)) = val; does not make a sense. The compiler shall issue an error.

Comment: What is `ELEMENT_SIZE`? I assume it’s not 1 so you’re pointing outside the buffer quite fast. Pointer arithmetic works based on type (here int), not bytes, so multiplying with anything else than 1 goes out, causes undefined behavior, and may very well account for this

Comment: You have to *use* the pointer value returned by `realloc()` not throw it away. The original `vec->ptr` may now be invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`.

Now if we do this transformation of `*(vec->ptr + (ELEMENT_SIZE * index)` we get `vec->ptr[ELEMENT_SIZE * index]`. Which is probably not what you had in mind.

Assuming that `sizeof(int)` (what `ELEMENT_SIZE` expands to) is `4` (very common) then attempting to use index `2` will actually use index `8` (`4 * 2`). Which is out of bounds of your allocated memory (as it only contains `5` elements), and leads to undefined behavior.

The solution is simple: Don't multiply with `ELEMENT_SIZE` when accessing elements of your array.

---

You have another two very serious errors as well:

```
realloc(vec->ptr, ELEMENT_SIZE * (vec->len + 1))
*(vec->ptr + (ELEMENT_SIZE * vec->len)) = val;
```

Because the first line is missing the semicolon, the statement becomes

```
realloc(vec->ptr, ELEMENT_SIZE * (vec->len + 1)) * (vec->ptr + (ELEMENT_SIZE * vec->len)) = val;
```

And that doesn't make any sense.

The second problem, besides the missing semicolon, is that [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) can allocate a *new* memory area, which it then returns a pointer to. That would make the old pointer invalid as it then points to memory that you no longer own. Always use what `realloc` returns.

But also note that `realloc` can return `NULL`, in which case the old pointer remains valid, so always use a temporary variable:

```
int *new_ptr = realloc(vec->ptr, ELEMENT_SIZE * (vec->len + 1));
if (new_ptr == NULL)
{
    // TODO: Handle error
}
vec->ptr = new_ptr;
vec->ptr[vec->len] = val;
```

Comment: The 2nd serious problem was indeed the cause of my problem, thank you. Regarding the original answer, what if ptr and index are of different types(such as uin8_t and size_t)?

Comment: @archbishop It doesn't matter what type the pointer is, indexing is always done in *elements* not bytes.